# Appcompat title manipulation

Tags: android, title, android-appcompat

I am using appcompatv7 for my app. In strings, I have defined `Login` and on logging in, the default action bar text `Login` is shown, but I can't manipulate that text (except deleting it in strings).

I need to change the color or the text alignment, but there is no option to do so, neither in styles nor in layout in the login page.

Also when I put an icon on that action bar using:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.login);
```

I also can't manipulate the alignment or anything else.

Comment: you have to do this stuff (style, color) in your xml file

Comment: have you do this ? show your xml code to get help easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
   >
```

This is header of my xml file.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="colorPrimary">#008000</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

This is my styles file.